# Azure and Intranet sites. IE works, but Chrome/FF do not

Tags: azure, google-chrome, firefox

On my Azure environment, I have two servers running IIS/ColdFusion
I can access the pages using IE/Edge fine. No issues.

But when I attempt to connect to the same pages using either Chrome or FF, both fail>
Chrome returns with "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"
FF says something similar.
But IE 11 does work fine.

Also to add to it.
On the local server itself, I can use IE and get a web page.
Using Chrome or FF produces the same problem.  So I am guessing it is an issue w/ IIS?

Some additional info:
We have a site on the server which is just HTTP, all browsers can connect to it fine.
Only when accessing the SSL sites does it fail.
We only have TLS 1.2 enabled on the servers and PCI compliant Cipher suites.
Is there something in IIS that could be causing FF/Chrome to barf with the SSL connection but IE is allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out
Somehow (not sure how), all the cipher suites but one were disabled/removed.
Updated the Group Policy with all the cipher suites needed.
Update the GP on the machines, rebooted 
Sites are now accessible.